# Rails handling of data-remote=true forms on chromium

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Two browsers are submitting a form from the same action.  However the log shows one browsers request being handled by rails as HTML, while the other - correctly - as JS, given the `data-remote="true"` attribute.

The former (mistaken) one is an older version of Chromium implemented by Opera.
I realise that the age of the browser is a pertinent element, but what I fail to comprehend is: what exactly is going on here so that Rails perceives a request as local (HTML); it may have to do with rails ujs as `require("@rails/ujs").start()` is included in application.js pack.

Is  there is a way to protect against such a case happening in practice (i.e. someone using an older browser) ?

```
<form action="/cartitems" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="_aBI2D7eHLVRVgXJp6vhC5LlvxrvfhsOO77WAJk5_kkhfJHA2t5ZfeKAirp0kOf12WLW_coCZSF7zaJ6QSO3HA">
        <input value="1.05" type="hidden" name="cartitem[price_ordered]" id="cartitem_price_ordered">
      <input value="3514" type="hidden" name="cartitem[article_id]" id="cartitem_article_id">
      <input value="false" type="hidden" name="cartitem[fulfilled]" id="cartitem_fulfilled">
        <input min="1" style="width: 69px; display: inline-block;" type="number" name="cartitem[q_order]" id="cartitem_q_order">
      <button name="button" type="submit" style="display: inline-block;">
        <p class="button" style="margin-top: 10px;"><i class="fa fa-cart-plus fa 3x"></i></p>
</button></form>

Started POST "/cartitems" for 9.999.36.103 at 2021-06-25 11:22:24 +0200
Cannot render console from 9.999.36.103! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255, ::1
Processing by CartitemsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "cartitem"=>{"price_ordered"=>"1.05", "article_id"=>"3514", "fulfilled"=>"false", "q_order"=>"2"}, "button"=>""}
```

Correct (and expected) handling:

```
<form action="/cartitems" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="I3D5RDclZxnP6f5yFhYIuI3GXlk2Gidt4c_FFZcsjOQwK-XxTy5pgyBn2KVefgMjRFe0yt-NKbN72z8OphRRWQ">
        <input value="1.05" type="hidden" name="cartitem[price_ordered]" id="cartitem_price_ordered">
      <input value="3514" type="hidden" name="cartitem[article_id]" id="cartitem_article_id">
      <input value="false" type="hidden" name="cartitem[fulfilled]" id="cartitem_fulfilled">
        <input min="1" style="width: 69px; display: inline-block;" type="number" name="cartitem[q_order]" id="cartitem_q_order">
      <button name="button" type="submit" style="display: inline-block;">
        <p class="button" style="margin-top: 10px;"><i class="fa fa-cart-plus fa 3x"></i></p>
</button></form>

Started POST "/cartitems" for 9.999.36.103 at 2021-06-25 11:21:42 +0200
Cannot render console from 9.999.36.103! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255, ::1
Processing by CartitemsController#create as JS
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "cartitem"=>{"price_ordered"=>"1.05", "article_id"=>"3514", "fulfilled"=>"false", "q_order"=>"2"}, "button"=>""}
```

Comment: Do you get any javascript errors in the malfunctioning version? Very likely its something with UJS indeed, hard to tell what. Could be some unsupported js feature that ruins the whole thing

Comment: The chromium dev tools console tab is a bit opaque to me. but it is logging XML requests and complaining about a zxing.js `this` not defined error (which I expect on this page).  No other errors, warning, info or verbose appear; but I am not certain the dev tool is configured properly.